# Can you set a rule to foward/redirect emails recieved in Office 365 to a contact list that you have created?

Tags: email, office365

I am in O365 and wondering if it is possible to redirect all emails received to a contact list instead of just a single contact. I created the rule, the only part I couldn't get was the including the contact list in receiving the redirected email. I am just wondering if it is even a possibility in Office 365. This is the error I receive when I try to include a contact list instead of a contact:

[image: Error I receive.]

Yes, I spelt the contact list correctly.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's possible - where did you enter the name?  You should be presented with a list from your Contacts folder where you can select Contacts or Contact Lists.  It will be displayed after you choose the action in the "Do all of the following" dropdown:

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I did, and I selected the contact list that appeared when the contact picker appeared. Then I got the error that is in the main post. Did you successfully add a contact list to the rule and save it?

Comment: OY! My bad! You're right - it doesn't work. I made a horrible assumption that it would. It also fails if you use a Contact List created in Outlook. However, if you try to create the rule in Outlook, it'll fail "nicely" and offer to extract the users from the List.